# Apache camel throwing Fatal Error :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-camel

I am trying to integrate kafka using apache camel and created a route to listen to kafka topic and process. But everytime this kafka listener receives any text message or json payload , it thorws
**Fatal Error :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog. org.xml.sax.SAXParseException**

Even after getting this exception , I am able to process that message but every time i get new message on kafka topic it throws same exception again.

If I post any message which is like xml , it does not throw above exception.

Any idea on how can i solve this and make this camel endpoint accept json payload ?

Update:
Using this route which I have copied from apache camel document

```
from("kafka:test?brokers=localhost:9092")
    .log("Message received from Kafka : ${body}")
    .log("    on the topic ${headers[kafka.TOPIC]}")
    .log("    on the partition ${headers[kafka.PARTITION]}")
    .log("    with the offset ${headers[kafka.OFFSET]}")
    .log("    with the key ${headers[kafka.KEY]}")
```

and I have imported following dependency in my spring boot application:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-kafka</artifactId>
    <version>2.25.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: SAXParseException occurs when something is not a XML. You should post your route here to see how we can help you

Comment: Updated question with route details

Comment: Have you tried explicitly defining the deserializer?

Comment: After further investigation I found out this issue is not related to Apache camel but because of some issue in configuration. Thank You to everyone here who took time to look into this issue.

Comment: what was the config issues running into the same issue now